# Firefox unaccesible spectrum cause sound object crash

Tags: firefox, soundmanager2, spectrum

I'm having a issue with [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) API.

I use whileplaying parameter to call a function where I obtain spectrum of the sound (Created in the API) and create a wave.

The problem resides when I open another flash object with a soundSpectrum the API throw following errors on the console:

```
"(Flash): getWaveformData() (waveform data) SecurityError: Error #2122"
"(Flash): computeSpectrum() (EQ data) SecurityError: Error #2122"
"sound: Data error: data unavailable: SecurityError: Error #2122"
```

And I'm not aviable to call the sound object again, this only happens in firefox.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Well I did few things here, isn't a total fix but work at last:

computeSpectrum try to access the sound card output but when isn't aviable throw a error (Managed in SoundManager2 by ondataerror event).

Add a External Callback from flash which returns `SoundMixer.areSoundsInaccessible()` then when the event ondataerror is call stops the music and start a loop waiting until the sound card output is acessible again and then restart the music (Including whileplaying event).

(I did modified the flash file and some parts of the code).

Hope this help someone but isn't the awnser I was looking for.